# Prevent sign-in immediately after sign-up (devise rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

How can I prevent automatic sign-in immediately after sign-up?? I have the following code inside the registrations_controller.rb, but it's not working!

```
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom registration_controller.rb to override default one. Good explanation how to do it here: https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/2343176

Then in custom controller recreate default create action but without `sign_up(resource_name, resource)`

This is the default `registration_controller.rb` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

This is create action without `sign_up(resource_name, resource)`:

```
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```